# Variable type specifier in C

Tags: c, variables

I just started in C programming and I know that "%d" defines that it will be a number value, as in:

```
int x = 9;

printf("X = %d", x);
getchar();
return 0;
```

but what are the other variable specifiers for C? (to define strings, and do they change for float, double, long, etc.?)

Comment: The format specifiers you're looking at are particular to functions like printf() and scanf(). Read about these functions and you'll find your answer in that documentation.

Comment: ... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ ...

Comment: Why all the downvotes? A beginner's misuse of terminology?

Comment: See the description of downvote, this question shows absolutely no research effort.

Comment: @skjaidev: How do you know the difference between "no research effort" and "would put effort into research but is an absolute beginner and has no idea how or where to do that research"?

Comment: I have high expectations: http://www.google.com/search?q=printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good summary of the specifiers available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders .

Answer (score 0):

Your question as phrased is meaningless. The `%d` is a format specifier, and has nothing to do with variable declarations.

If you were to google 'printf c', you would find many, many sites that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pick up a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie's [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628). It short but fully packed. Working through this book is well worth the time.

But as to your question, you're asking about [Format specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) for string literals. You'll probably also want to look at escape characters soon (e.g. `\n` for new lines). Fortunately, it's all in K&R (the above book), specifically on page 153 (2nd edition).